# Character constant ignore

Tags: c++, char, constants, special-characters, backslash

I need to compare variable value with backslash symbol:

```
char symbol;
/* assigning a value to
a variable */
if (symbol == '\') {
    // some action
}
```

But my Visual Studio recognizes it as a character constant. How can I ignore it?

Maybe there is a "r" prefix like in python:

`symbol = r'\'`

Comment: Any decent beginners learning or teaching resource should have the information needed to say how backslashes can be *escaped*. And I bet you have seen *escaped* characters before, like the newline `'\n'`

Comment: With that said, yes C++ also have something similar to Pythons raw strings. And they are *also* named "raw strings". So a quick search for that should also help you.

Comment: It is the same in most programming languages, including Python: `'\\'`

Comment: \ is a special character. It is used in combination with the following one to denote a single character. Ex.: \n denotes the end of line, \t a tabulation. If you want to introduce the single character \, as it is special you need the combination \\, so as a character literal `'\\'`.